# Типы сказуемых

Tags: синтаксис

Лена старалась показываться там пореже? Разве здесь не составное именное сказуемое?

Comment: Почему именное-то?

Answer (score 2):

Нет. Типичное составное глагольное.

*Я, честно говоря, в не в курсе современных школьных подходов, любую ли подобную конструкцию причисляют к составным глагольным (т.е. достаточно ли "модален" первый глагол, типа "думали послать искать купить выпить"), но в рассматриваемом примере почвы для сомнений я не вижу.*

Comment: В Вашем примере вопрос в границе сказуемого. "Думали послать" - составное глагольное сказуемое, а вот "искать купить выпить" - второстепенные члены.

Answer (score 2):

Здесь немного напрягает оборот "показываться пореже", его, наверное можно отнести к неразложимому сочетанию. Сравнить: Лена старалась приезжать туда пореже - здесь уж точно составное глагольное сказуемое. Тогда "старалась" - это связка с модальным значением (желание, стремление, старание), а вместо основного глагола  будет глагольное сочетание "показываться пореже".